# Connecting to Sql fails when I add code to my project to create a test admin in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I have a project set up using the identityserver4 quickstart template that works completely fine until I uncomment code to create a test admin. Then I get the error:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[100100]
tokenserviceapi |       An exception occurred in the database while iterating the results of a query for context type 'TokenServiceApi.Data.ApplicationDbContext'.
tokenserviceapi |       System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "TokenServiceDb" requested by the login. The login failed.
tokenserviceapi |       Login failed for user 'sa'.
```

This is the relevant code:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env,
                      UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
                      RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            EnsureRolesAsync(roleManager).Wait();
            EnsureTestAdminAsync(userManager).Wait();
        }
    }

        private static async Task EnsureRolesAsync(RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
    {
        var alreadyExists = await roleManager.RoleExistsAsync(Constants.AdministratorRole);

        if (alreadyExists) return;

        await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(Constants.AdministratorRole));
    }

    private static async Task EnsureTestAdminAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        var testAdmin = await userManager.Users
            .Where(x => x.UserName == "admin@email.local")
            .SingleOrDefaultAsync();

        if (testAdmin != null) return;

        testAdmin = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "admin@email.local", Email = "admin@email.local" };
        await userManager.CreateAsync(testAdmin, "NotSecure123!!");
        await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(testAdmin, Constants.AdministratorRole);
    }
```

If I comment out:

```
UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager
```

and

```
EnsureRolesAsync(roleManager).Wait();
EnsureTestAdminAsync(userManager).Wait();
```

It doesn't fail to connect to the sql db. What could cause this?

Comment: Calling `SomethingAsync().Wait()` is a strong indication that your solution is broken or will break.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I mean that you seem to _fighting_ the fundamentally asynchronous nature of the APIs by trying to force asynchronous operations to run in a startup method and to accomplish by trying to make them block. When that happens, take a step back because it is definitely the wrong approach.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not really sure what to do. I copied the code from a tutorial project that works. Why would it work there, but not here?

Comment: I've checked six tutorials through Udemy, Pluralsight, and books. They all do it this way. Could you show me an example of doing it a different way?

Comment: You are saying that they all have a `Configure` implementation in startup.cs that calls `Wait` on an async method? That they all access the database from this method?

Comment: Yes. That is what I said.

Comment: Very doubtful. None of Microsoft's examples behave that way.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/i03yzj

http://prntscr.com/i03z6h
Microsoft's example.

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/issues/4134

Comment: Can you please link this fabled microsoft example that doesn't use async and .wait()?

The link you sent is literally a microsoft employee saying that put async methods in every single one of their examples.

Nice quick edit to save yourself. Why are you like this?